# Ubuntu: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly (Tried all options)

Tags: maven, ubuntu

when run mvn --version getting the below error

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Java is already installed find more details below
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
(Note- I even tried with JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)

Any solutions will be helpful.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH